# Getting "Invalid date/time on SAXException and NumberFormatException" error while receiving web service response

Tags: java, web-services, automation

I am automating web service Testing with Java.I am able to post the Request successfully but while it returning the Response,it throwing " org.apache.axis.client.Call invoke
SEVERE: Exception:org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid date/time
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time" error.

Below is the XSD java format::

```
    elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
    elemField.setFieldName("GDateField");
    elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "gDate.field"));
    elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "date"));
    elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
    elemField.setNillable(false);
    elemField.setItemQName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "Datefield"));
    typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
```

The "date" datatype in elemField.setXmlType causing this problem.I tried with Calendar,date and SimpleDateFormat package but no luck..PFA below image.

[Error Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZSTn.png)

Comment: Why are there so many spaces in the link `http://www.w3.org   /2001/XMLSchema`?
It should be `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`

Comment: Typo error,changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The received date in response doesn't fall under the W3 format.After I changed my response then it is working

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you solved it yourself.

Comment: If it worked for u can u plz post the  date  format that worked  for  u